# Decision tree evaluation using Prolog

Tags: prolog

To represent the function

```
f(x) =
    if x < -2 then -1
    else
        if x > 2 then +1
        else
            0
```

The decision tree is represented as

```
[-1, [lt, -2], [1, [gt, 2], 0] ]
```

Similarly, to represent the function

```
f(x) =
    if x < 0 then
       if x < -3 then -1
       else 0
    else
       if x < 3 then +1
       else +2
```

we use the tree:

```
[-1,[lt,-3],0],[lt,0],[1,[lt,3],2]]
```

How do I write Prolog code for the `evaluate( DT, X, Y )` predicate that holds if Y is the value obtained by evaluating the decision tree DT on the value X?

Sample input and output is as follows:

```
?- evaluate([-1,[lt,-2],[1,[gt,2],0]],1,X).
X = 0 ? ;

?- evaluate([[-1,[lt,-3],0],[lt,0],[1,[lt,3],2]],7,X).
X = 2 ? ;
```

Comment: What do you mean by asking is it a homework...I was trying to solve Prolog problems so that I can learn it..Am able to do good with simple problems..but finding difficulty with tough ones,,,self study has its limits.. :)

Comment: If the problem is homework we try to give a hint rather than a full solution. That way when your prof searches for the problems they assigned you and they find your question here, you won't get thrown out of school for cheating/plagiarism, because you'll have had to do some of the work yourself.

Comment: Someone spent time trying to answer your question.  Its rude to delete their work without reason.  Please consider their answer and accept if correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm finding your intermediate representation a little counter-intuitive. Would it be fair to say that the lists are meant to be understood as a 3-tuple, like: `[TrueValue, Condition, ElseValue]`, where `TrueValue` and `FalseValue` can be values or other conditional 3-tuples? I'm going to answer assuming this is the right understanding.

What you've got here is a basic abstract syntax tree (AST). We're going to have two patterns: a value, or a 3-tuple. Evaluating a value is easy:

```
evaluate(Value, _, Value) :- number(Value).
```

With this in hand, evaluating a conditional is pretty easy:

```
evaluate([TrueCase, Condition, FalseCase], X, Result) :-
  evaluate_condition(Condition, X) 
      -> evaluate(TrueCase, X, Result)
       ; evaluate(FalseCase, X, Result).
```

I've moved the condition checking itself to a separate predicate. This makes it convenient to add new operators. Now we just need to code it:

```
evaluate_condition([lt, Y], X) :- X < Y.
evaluate_condition([gt, Y], X) :- X > Y.
```

This is even a little better than you were hoping, because it doesn't produce spurious choice points:

```
?- evaluate([-1,[lt,-2],[1,[gt,2],0]],1,X).
X = 0.

?- evaluate([[-1,[lt,-3],0],[lt,0],[1,[lt,3],2]],7,X).
X = 2.
```